# How to add an SVG hover event for text on a rectangle?

Tags: svg, hover

I have an SVG with multiple rectangles which contain text. When hovering over a rectangle, I want to have a small shadow. Since one can't add text inside the rect element, I've added it after, which means that the text actually shows up on top of the rectangle, so when I hover over the text, the shadow isn't shown.

Since text is after rect, I can't use the sibling selector. I've also tried using a group, but with no success. Here is a small [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a71ufrse/) of what I'm trying to get (and the code).

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .slip {
        fill: blue;
      }
      .st {
        fill: white;
      }
      .slip:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
        filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="slips">
    <rect class="slip" x="10" y="10" width="80" height="50"/>
    <text class="st" x="20" y="30">1000</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson awesome, that worked!! If you want to add this as an answer, for me to mark it as the correct one, please do! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the text to be `pointer-events: none;`

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .slip {
        fill: blue;
      }
      .st {
        fill: white;
        pointer-events: none;
      }
      .slip:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
        filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="slips">
    <rect class="slip" x="10" y="10" width="80" height="50"/>
    <text class="st" x="20" y="30">1000</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```